# winmail.dat attachments on Evolution (Ubuntu Gnome 13.10)

Tags: gnome, 13.10, evolution, attachment

Evolution doesn't show the attachments in the mails sent from Outlook, instead it shows a winmail.dat file.

I have already installed `evolution-plugins-experimental` and restarted Evolution. I also rebooted the computer completely, but there is no `tnef-attachments` plugin listed under Edit->Plugins, and the emails showing still winmail.dat as attachment.

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 distribution. I don't know how to solve this problem so that I can see the attachments from Outlook users.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ends up here looking for a solution, the problem is most likely [a bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700778) that arose in Evolution 3.5 when TNEF handling passed from a plugin to a module.

It was fixed in Evolution 3.12.9+ and 3.13.8+, so you will need to use a distribution that offers one of them or above, which is the case of [Ubuntu GNOME 15.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1390466/comments/8) and above (but 16.04 is recommended, as 15.04 is not supported anymore, and 15.10 only has 2 more months of support at the time of writing).